# Problems with the integration of Django 3 and Vue 3

Tags: django, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3

I have been trying to integrate Django 3 with Vue 3 for two days and I have partly succeeded but not as I would like.

Stage. The idea is to use Vue 3 for components that require Javascript and are not important for SEO like booking forms, etc …

Integrate by using django-webpack-loader to inject the bundle into django templates.

```
const BundleTracker = require("webpack-bundle-tracker");

module.exports = {
  publicPath: "http://0.0.0.0:8080/",
  outputDir: './dist/',

    pages: {
        main: {
            // entry for the page
      entry: 'src/main.js',
    }
    },

  chainWebpack: config => {

    config.optimization
      .splitChunks(false)

    config
      .plugin('BundleTracker')
      .use(BundleTracker, [{filename: './webpack-stats.json'}])

    config.resolve.alias
      .set('__STATIC__', 'public')

    config.devServer
      .public('http://0.0.0.0:8080')
      .host('0.0.0.0')
      .port(8080)
      .hotOnly(true)
      .watchOptions({poll: 1000})
      .https(false)
      .headers({"Access-Control-Allow-Origin": ["\*"]})
  }
};
```

This is the content of the ** main.js ** that is the entry point of the Vue3 app

```
import { createApp, reactive, ref } from ‘vue’

const app = createApp({
el: ‘#app’,
delimiters: [’[[’, ‘]]’],
setup() {

const data = {
  returned_task: ref(''),
  temp_task: ref(''),
  modify_index: ref(-1),
  tasks: reactive([]),
}

const methods = {
  select: (index) => {
    if (data.modify_index.value === index){
      data.modify_index.value = -1;
    } else {
      data.modify_index.value = index
      data.temp_task.value = data.tasks[data.modify_index.value]
    }
  },
  deleteSelected: () => {
    data.tasks.splice(data.modify_index.value, 1);
    data.modify_index.value = -1;
  },
  updateSelected: () => {
    data.tasks.splice(data.modify_index.value, 1, data.temp_task.value);
    data.modify_index.value = -1;
  }
}

// created lifecycle event is not needed  but let's mock a delay
setTimeout(() => {
  data.tasks.splice(0, 0, ...['do this ‍', 'and that ']);
}, 120);


return {
  ...data,
  ...methods
}

}
})

app.mount(’#app’)
```

and it’s in the html template where Vue should be rendered

```
<div id="app">
   [[modify_index]]
      <ul>
        <li v-for="task in tasks">[[task]]</li>
      </ul>
</div>
```

What happens is that nothing is rendered inside the div #app, no error is shown, and I could not find many references on the web.

Thanks to whoever can give me a hand.